# Where does ray stdout go?

Tags: python-3.x, ray

For ray remote jobs, I can see stderr gets printed to the driver session.

However, is there a way to get the stdout for remote jobs? Checking individual job logs can be very useful for debugging.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Mac, try checking the path
`/tmp/ray/session_latest/logs/*`.
This should contain `stdout` and `stderr` of the Ray cluster. 
Note that the `ray` directory is probably removed if your cluster is shut down.

Comment: I've already looked at those paths and, while there are indeed some logs there, they don't contain the stdout of my jobs. In particular, I see files like `python-worker-*` and `worker-*`, which contain ray specific logs. Nothing that come from my remote functions.

Comment: Another way you can see logs is to use dashboard. Once you run a Ray cluster, you can access to your dashboard through localhost:8265. (URL should be shown in the console). If your tasks have logs, you should be able to see them through dashboard.